# CSS wrap behaviour white-space

Tags: html, css, whitespace

I have the following:

[image]

I don't want to break the tags, so I specified the `white-space: nowrap` option to the span. However, now I have the following problem: the line doesn't break at all.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Relevant HTML:

```html
<td class="tags-column">
  <span class="library-tags"><i class="fa fa-tag"></i>&nbsp;test</span> ....
</td>
```

Comment: whitespace:pre-wrap more info here : https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/whitespace/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following style to `.library-tags`:

```css
.library-tags {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left
}
```